# Which tracer bean should we use with Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micrometer-tracing

In Spring Boot we migrate from Sleuth to micrometer-tracing and with `management.tracing.enabled` both beans are available and both store the trace: `brave.Tracer` and `io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer`.

But which tracer bean should we use with Spring Boot 3 `brave.Tracer` or `io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer` according to best practices and the current design?